# How to say Shining through me

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, prepositions

I am trying to say “you are shining through me” I am not sure if the meaning of it is correct.

I want to say, you shine me, you are the light for me.

Shining through me or shining on me or anyhing else?

How can I say that? Thanks for your help

Comment: for example,  you are my light source who shines through me

Comment: When you say "you are shining through me", you are the beneficiary; whereas "you are the light for me" means I am the beneficiary.

Comment: You're not being very transparent.

Comment: 'Shining through me' would necessitate One living within me, in union with my being in a spiritual sense, not an external source of alternative life - I would say.

Comment: I didn’t understand. If I say, “through me” does it mean really through like a window? I wanna say for example  you are the sun shining me. Thing Like that

Comment: I want to say I am the beneficiary

Comment: It is very tricky. If I say you shine me on, it means a bad thing. I just want to say I am the beneficiary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you are shining through me**

As in:

> Your soul brightly shines (my being, upon me, upon my day etc.)

**shine**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shine)

ps:  the verb shine has two different past tenses, shined and shone

Answer (score 1):

"You're the light of my life."

I coouldn't find a good online reference for it.  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/the_light_of_someone's_life says it means just "A much loved person." but the examples there such as "All I will say is that she is the light of my life and I am really happy." show it also means they're the most loved person for the speaker.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Is there any way to say that by using the word “shine”? Because, the poetry needs it.

Comment: In my native language, it is very easy to say but in English, it is very tricky. I can say the oppsite mistakenly while I want to say “you are the light of my life”.

Comment: For example, Nietzsche says: “what would be all your happiness if you had not those for whom you shine!”